# Check ranges with Bash using regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix

I've made a helper function to determine if a specified length to generate a password is valid. How can I translate this if conditional to regex to check the ranges of 8-64?

```
# Check to see if password length is valid
# @param $1 length specified by the user
# @return True (0) if not valid, False (1) if we're okay
# Usage: if is_valid "$length"
is_valid() {
  local length="$1"

  if (( "$length" < 8 || "$length" > 64 )); then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi  
}
```

Comment: `^.{8, 64}$` as simple as that

Comment: So I could encapsulate that in a variable like this, correct? `match="^.{8,64}$"` @HamZa

Comment: I'm not familiar with bash, that's why I posted the regex as a comment :p

Comment: I'll test it now. I know to test for a range like 10-15, I would say [something like [0-1][0-5]. For some reason, this one threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a normal pattern matching instead of a regex:

```
function is_valid () {
    [[ $1 == @([8-9]|[1-5][0-9]|[6][0-4]) ]]
}
```

Regex would be similar:

```
function is_valid () {
    [[ $1 =~ ^([8-9]|[1-5][0-9]|[6][0-4])$ ]]
}
```

I do not find any of them more readable than plain

```
function is_valid () {
    (( 8 <= $1 && $1 <= 64 ))
}
```

Note that `if` and `return` are not needed.

Comment: I'm so used to doing that trick with return, I have a C background. I didn't know that just using `[[`` would suffice. Why doesn't the regex Hamza gave me work the way yours does? I didn't think the pattern would be so long.

Comment: @user520720: Hamza's regex matches strings of length 8 to 64, but not the numbers.

Comment: I think I got it, tell me what you think: `if [[ ! $length =~ ([8-9]|1[0-5])$ ]]`

Comment: I made it validate passwords from 8-15 instead.

Comment: @user520720: Missing `^` anchor makes it (not) match 6668 or 66615, too.

Comment: Oops! Glad you caught that. Corrected: `if [[ ! $length =~ ^([8-9]|1[0-5])$ ]]`

Comment: @user520720: Now 1, 2, ..., 7, 16, 17 ... pass the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
local length=${#1}
if [ $length -lt 8 ] || [ $length -gt 64 ]; then
```

rather than accepting the length as a parameter. This way you can calculate the length of the password without the user having to provide additional input. But if you really want to use RegEx, HamZa's regex is right. I believe it can be placed into a variable but you may need to change it to

```
"^.{8,64}\$"
```

Comment: extglob does not affect regular expressions, but extended glob patterns.

Comment: @choroba so it wouldn't affect grep -e?

Comment: @ive_got_heem: Not at all.